# Quick launch strange behaviour

Tags: navigation, quick-launch, spnavigationnode

I am accessing the quick launch nodes programmatically by using

```
SPWeb currWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = currWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
foreach (SPNavigationNode node in nodes)
{
   ...
}
```

Strange thing is that there are more nodes in the collection than i see in SharePoint in the quick launch!
The extra nodes that are in the collection are the different sub webs.

But i only want to use the "real" elements that are in the quick launch. How can i access them?

It is since i turned on the publishing features i have this issue. And using

```
if (PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(currWeb)) { 
   PublishingWeb pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(currWeb); 
   nodes = pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes; 
}
```

to get the nodes gives the same results.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( (node.Properties["NodeType"] != null && node.Properties["NodeType"].ToString() =="Area" && pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites)
  || (node.Properties["NodeType"] != null && node.Properties["NodeType"].ToString() == "Page" && pubWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages) 
  || (node.Properties["NodeType"] == null))
{ //display here }
```

Try the above logic on whether or not to hide the navigation node. Substitute Global with Current. I fixed mine for the Global navigation.

Here is a link to more information about the property [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.nodetypes(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.nodetypes%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is normal behavior to facilitate the "display subsites" option in the navigation. You'll likely need to do some additional logic on each node to determine if it's a subweb or not and display accordingly.

Comment: But if i do that, it will also filter the subwebs that are manually added to the quick launch. I only want those 'hidden' items filtered.